# Registered lookup not working in Druid

Tags: lookup, druid

I'm working with druid for a short time now and I'm testing the registered lookup functionality.

I've already created the lookup under the http://:/druid/coordinator/v1/lookups, as following:

```
{
    "__default": {
        "home_post_code": {
          "type": "map",
          "map": {"13210": "Syracuse, NY"}
        }
    }
}
```

As far as I understood, this mapping should replace all the occurrences with value "13210" with "Syracuse, NY", for the dimension "home_post_code" declared in the query section below:

```
    ...
    },
    "dimensions": [
        "home_post_code",
        {
            "type":"registeredLookup",
            "dimension" : "home_post_code",
            "outputName" :  "home_post_code_description",
            "lookup":"home_post_code",
            "retainMissingValue": true,
            "injective": false
        }
    ],
    ...
```

The problem is that when I execute the query, the value in the column "home_post_code_description" is not replaced according to the mapping.

I'm able to list the lookup in the http://:/druid/listen/v1/lookups, so I believe it is properly registered.

What am I missing here? Should I change any configuration of anything?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can try few of the things to get it resolve.

1. Delete all the lookups which you are not using
2. either use "__default" as tier name or mention you tier whatever you want but don't forget to mention in ALL your runtime.properties with as
   druid.lookup.lookupTierIsDatasource=false
   druid.lookup.lookupTier=_default_tier
3. make sure GET is working on that lookup (see the documentation for get api for lookup )

Forexample:
A typical lookup query would look like

````
{  
   "intervals":[  
      "Your interval"
   ],
   "granularity":"all",
   "queryType":"groupBy",
   "threshold":1000,
   "dataSource":"your datasource name",
   "aggregations":[  
      {  
         "type":"doubleSum",
         "name":"sum",
         "fieldName":"your field"
      }
   ],
   "dimensions":[  
      {  
         "type":"default",
         "dimension":"your dimention mentioned in lookup- Key",
         "outputName":"anyoutput name",
         "outputType":<"STRING"|"LONG"|"FLOAT">,
         "name":"your registered lookup name"
      },
      {  

          "type" : "extraction",
          "dimension" : "your dimention mentioned in lookup- Key",
          "outputName" : "anyout put name",
          "outputType": "<"STRING"|"LONG"|"FLOAT">,
          "extractionFn" : {
               "type":"registeredLookup",
                "lookup":"your registered lookup name",
                "retainMissingValue":true

            }

      }
   ],
   "metric":{  

   }
}`
```
````

This will work.. After struggling alot i finally break this problem into solutions

Answer (score 1):

Your query is probably wrong. You should use the [ExtractionDimensionSpec](http://druid.io/docs/latest/querying/dimensionspecs.html#extraction-dimensionspec) with the Extraction Function being a [Registered Lookup Extraction](http://druid.io/docs/latest/querying/dimensionspecs.html#registered-lookup-extraction-function) Function.

```
  "dimensions" : [ {
      "type" : "extraction",
      "dimension" : "home_post_code",
      "outputName" : "home_post_code_description",
      "extractionFn": {
          "type":"registeredLookup",
          "lookup": "home_post_code",
          "retainMissingValue":true,
          "injective":false
      }
  } ]
```

Comment: Not only that, the type of lookup in druid is not registeredLookup, I believe it is a Map Lookup, so even with the right query for registered lookup it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You should use extractionFunction which transform dimension values using the given extraction function.

```
"dimensions": [
    {
        "dimension": "id",
        "type": "extraction",
        "extractionFn": {
          "type":"lookup",
          "lookup": {
            "type":"map",
            "map":{
                "13210": "Syracuse, NY"
            }
          },
          "retainMissingValue":false,
          "injective":false
        }
    }
]
```