# Lookup [ lookup_table ] not found - Apache Druid

Tags: lookup, druid

I recently have created a sample lookup table in druid using postman as follows :

```sh
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8888/druid/coordinator/v1/lookups/config' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "hot_tier": {
        "province": {
          "version": "1.1",
          "lookupExtractorFactory": {
        "type": "map",
        "map": {
          "10": "province1",
          "61": "province2"
        }
      }
        }
    }
}'
```

it's were appeared in `Lookup Web UI`.
when i got into testing this lookup table , i issued this query :

```sql
SELECT cityCode,cityName, LOOKUP(CAST(provinceCode AS VARCHAR), "province") as province
from cities
```

but I got an error message :

```
Suggestion: Replace "province" with 'province'

Error: Plan validation failed

org.apache.calcite.runtime.CalciteContextException: From line 1, column 65 to line 1, column 74: Column 'province' not found in any table

org.apache.calcite.tools.ValidationException
```

i realized the error and replaced `double quotes` with `single quotes`, but this time the error changed into :

```
Error: Unknown exception

Lookup [province] not found

org.apache.druid.java.util.common.ISE
```

What's wrong this time?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Gupta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51536306/1743724), I added the following settings in the  Druid `environment` file :

```
druid_lookup_lookupTierIsDatasource=false
druid_lookup_lookupTier=hot_tier
```

after the cluster restarted, my query get back results.